How to display a link to the npm package from within a GitHub repository
I have a GitHub repository. I published it as a package to npm via adding URL in the package.json. Now I'm able to see the GitHub repo of the package in npm.
However, I'm not able to see the npm package in the packages section of the GitHub repository.

When you click to publish a package you basically cannot add the link to the npm page of the package
The reason is I already published the package, I just want to display it here
Looks like the only chance is removing the package from npm, deploying it from scratch via GitHub Actions.
https://i.sstatic.net/DaGjN6f4.png


It would only show there if it was published on GitHub Packages, not (or not only) on npm.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
